# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data form OMDB database to display movies. Initially I have implemented click event to call data and no errors were found. But when I switch to `keyup` event I got this error.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
> at fetchMovie.getMovies.then.res (main.js:27)
> fetchMovie.getMovies.then.res @ main.js:27
> async function (async)
> searchInput.addEventListener @ main.js:19

```
let searchInput = document.getElementById('search')

class fetchData {
constructor() {
    this.apiKey = 'here is APIKey'
}

async getMovies(movie) {
    const movieRes = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${this.apiKey}&s=${movie}`)
    const moveData = await movieRes.json()
    return {
        moveData
    }
}
  }
const fetchMovie = new fetchData

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
let input = e.target.value

if (input !== '') {
    fetchMovie.getMovies(input)
        .then(res => {
            let data = res.moveData.Search
            let output = ''
            data.forEach(movie => {
                output += `
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="${movie.Poster}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">${movie.Title}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">${movie.Year}</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
                </div>`
            });
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = output;
        })
}
e.preventDefault();
})
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

**ERROR fixed with empty images also added keyup event. No errors in console**

```
    let searchInput = document.getElementById('search');

class fetchData {

    constructor() {
        this.apiKey = '884df292'
    }

    async getMovies(movie) {
        const movieRes = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${this.apiKey}&s=${movie}`)
        const moveData = await movieRes.json()
        return {
            moveData
        }
    }
}
const fetchMovie = new fetchData

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let input = e.target.value;

    if (input !== '') {
        fetchMovie.getMovies(input)
            .then(res => {
                let data = res.moveData.Search
                console.log(data)
                if (!data) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    let output = ''
                    data.forEach(movie => {
                        let poster
                        if (movie.Poster === "N/A") {
                            poster = `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg`
                        } else {
                            poster = movie.Poster
                        }
                        output += `
                    <div class="col-md-3 movie-card">
                    <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="${poster}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">${movie.Title}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">${movie.Year}</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    </div>`
                    });
                    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = output;
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: You should definetly add proper error handling if you are depending on user input

Comment: There is probably an error in how you fetch the movies. I'm not familiar with the API, but you may have a typo two lines above your error. You typed `res.moveData` when you may have meant `res.movieData`

Comment: Try logging what `res.moveData` is.

Comment: @MichaelKarpinski There is no `movieData` anywhere though, `moveData` works just fine - pretty sure it was just an abbreviation, not a typo

Comment: `res.moveData` is an array of movies

Comment: i am also getting this kind of error

**/C:/Users/Desktop/movieinfo-master/N/A:1 GET file:///C:/Users/Damian/Desktop/movieinfo-master/N/A 0 ()**

Comment: If `res.moveData` is an array of movies, then it's not an object with a property of `Search`, so of course accessing `moveData.Search` would be undefined...

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry i logged `res.moveData.Search` and this is array

`res.moveData` is an object with property of Search where my array is

Comment: I'm doubtful. Could you edit your question with the log results?

Comment: added screenshot, status is after you stop typing home.

in my opinion when you type one letter it will not sent an array to forEach so data is empty and forEach can;t work

Comment: I am 99% sure problem is that `keyup` event. Because when i had a button with `click` event everything was ok. I think problem is when i start typing even one letter function is being called and first data comming form APi is empty array so `forEach` has no array to loop. how to check/call `forEach` when there will be array?

Comment: What is `Search` in `let data = res.moveData.Search`? Just a property with the value of an array?

Comment: `Search` is where array of movie objects are stored (see screenshot) if you expand this array inside is what i want i am inserting this data into template string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the log screenshot you first get and `undefined` logged. That is most likely because your fetch happens for each key press, and if you search the API for a single character (*which is what you sent  with the first `keyup`*) you get back no results and thus the `forEach` fails.

Either check if data has a value before doing the `forEach` or don't even send a fetch if the search string is a single character.

```
let data = res.moveData.Search
let output = ''
if (!data) return; //early break if not results where returned.
```

or change `if (input !== '') {`  to

```
if (input.trim().length > 1) { // only do the fetch if more than one characters where entered
```

although you might still get no results even if you sent more than one characters so the 1st approach is safer.

Comment: true i have same thought. Could you please edit my code to include tihs validation??

Comment: @Damian just added two snippets for it.

Comment: worked.

but i have another thing

/C:/Users/Damian/Desktop/movieinfo-master/N/A:1 GET file:///C:/Users/Damian/Desktop/movieinfo-master/N/A 0 ()
Image (async)
fetchMovie.getMovies.then.res @ main.js:41
Promise.then (async)
searchInput.addEventListener @ main.js:24

Comment: This is still incorrect, if the user searches for `barbara` and the results for `barbar` return after the results for `barbara` (eventhough the request started earlier) then incorrect results would be shown.

Comment: @Damian about the error you get. That is because some images do not have a poster and they return "N/A" for that field. You then try to set an image to that url and the error happens. You need to check if the poster is "N/A" and only if it is not add it to your code.

Comment: @Damian for the issue of a request (*since they are asynchronous*) end after one following it, you should abort the previous requests when sending a new one. See AbortController Interface on how to do it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli hey, thanks for explaining, that `abort()` method looks great. but actually i do not know how to implement it correctly could you please add snippet or wokring example? thanks. i am a junior level dev.

for now i will stick with button event....;/

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli added solution to my question. no errors in console

Comment: I faced the same problem, i solved this problem adding if condition like this - if(jsonData) then statements...